# imgbb upload image in an album via api

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I have a trouble with using imgbb API
via imgbb API i've been trying to upload an image to the album that i created on imgbb. but i couldn't find any of informations so far... (i've been googling for 3hours lol)
anyone knows what to add for saving images in an album?

here are my codes.

thanks for reading :)

```
let body = new FormData()
body.set('key', 'my-api-key')
body.append('image', File)


axios.post('https://api.imgbb.com/1/upload/', body)
    .then((response) => {
        console.log('response', response)
        console.log('response URL', response.data.data.image.url)
        console.log('success')
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log('error', error)
        alert('try agian')
    })  enter code here
```

Answer (score -1):

From the doc

```
curl --location --request POST "https://api.imgbb.com/1/upload?expiration=600&key=YOUR_CLIENT_API_KEY" --form "image=R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7"
```

try this

```
let payload = new FormData()
payload.append('image', File)


axios.post('https://api.imgbb.com/1/upload?expiration=600&key=YOUR_CLIENT_API_KEY', payload)
    .then((response) => {
        console.log('response', response)
        console.log('response URL', response.data.data.image.url)
        console.log('success')
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log('error', error)
        alert('try agian')
    })
```

Comment: thanks for the answer :) what you suggesting is, I think, for uploading a photo on imgbb server. but for uploading a photo isn't a problem for me. im having a trouble to upload image in an album(folder) on my imgbb server :(